# Shorter way to integrate $\int \frac{x^9}{(x^2+4)^6} \, \mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, partial-fractions

$$
I=\int \frac{x^9}{(x^2+4)^6}\mathrm{d}x
$$
Yeah I know, I can substitute:
$$t=x^2+4\text{ or }2\tan\theta$$
So that:
$$I=\frac12\int\frac{(t-4)^4}{t^6}\mathrm{d}t\text{ or } I=2^{-2}\int\tan^9\theta\cos^{10}\theta\mathrm{d}\theta$$
Both of which are a long tedious way* to solve, is there any easier method?

**Update:** I am not asking among these two, I am asking any "substitution" except these two, which is shorter.

**Edit:** I am very sorry I missed the ^$6$ in question.

---

- Use Binomial Theorem for first and then divide by $t^6$, then integrate term wise.
- $\require{cancel}\cancel{\text{Use Reduction formula for second or integration by parts.}}$

  ---

[image]

Comment: The one with $t$ is quick.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I am not asking among these two, I am asking any "substitution" except these two, which is shorter.

Comment: You seem to be given answers: In this case it is usually easier to take derivatives of all the answers to check whether they match the integrand.

Comment: @achillehui It would be helpful if you'd mention details about this in your answer[not necessary]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint :**

Rewrite the integrand as
$$\frac{x^9}{x^2+4}=x^7-4x^5+16x^3+\frac{256x}{x^2+4}-64x.$$

---

**Edit :**

The OP was changed into
$$
\int\frac{x^9}{(x^2+4)^6}\ dx.
$$
Use $x=2\tan\theta\ \Rightarrow\ dx=2\sec^2\theta\ d\theta$.
$$
\int\frac{x^9}{(x^2+4)^6}\ dx=\frac14\int\tan^9\theta\ \cos^{10}\theta\ d\theta=\frac14\int\sin^9\theta\cos\theta\ d\theta.
$$
Now, set $t=\sin\theta\ \Rightarrow\ dt=\cos\theta\ d\theta$.
$$
\int\frac{x^9}{(x^2+4)^6}\ dx=\frac14\int t^9 dt=\frac1{40}t^{10}+C,
$$
where $\sin\theta=\dfrac x{\sqrt{x^2+4}}$. The answer is $\color{blue}{\text{D}}$.

Comment: Darn, beat me! :) +1

Comment: @AhaanRungta +1 too Brilliant buddy :)

Comment: sorry see the edit

Comment: I feel very sorry, hope my upvote compensates

Comment: @Aditya It's okay; no need to be sorry! To compensate, you should probably give me a +500 bounty. Haha, just kidding. =P

Comment: In a way, this shifts the burden to division. OP's $t$-substitution makes the division easy.

Comment: sometimes you hesitate to proceed fearing the complexity of problem, as I did after the second substitution

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to use a substitution quite yet. If you long-divide the integrand, you get $$\frac{x^9}{x^2+4}=x^7-4x^5+16x^3+\frac{256x}{x^2+4}-64x.$$Now, it is quite simple if the integrate term-by-term. Finishing things off: $$ \begin {align*} \displaystyle\int \frac {x^9}{x^2+4} \, \mathrm{d}x &= \displaystyle\int \left( \frac{x^9}{x^2+4}=x^7-4x^5+16x^3+\frac{256x}{x^2+4}-64x \right) \, \mathrm{d}x \\&= \frac {x^8}{8} - \frac {2}{3} x^6 + 4x^4 - 64x + 256 \displaystyle\int \frac {x}{x^2 + 4} \, \mathrm{d}x. \end {align*} $$The last integral can be done with an easy substitution.

---

*Edit*: So apparently the problem got changed again, but the same idea applies. You can re-write the new integrand as $$ \frac {x^9}{(x^2+4)^6} = \frac {x}{(x^2+4)^2} - \frac {16x}{(x^2+4)^3} + \frac {96x}{(x^2+4)^4} - \frac {256x}{(x^2+4)^5} + \frac {256x}{(x^2+4)^6}, $$ and use the substitution $u=x^2+4$ on each of these.

Comment: sorry see the edit

Comment: @Aditya You can still use the same approach. Edited.

Comment: Now this is long, try to match with given answers[see my edit]

Comment: @Aditya Hm, Tunk-Fey's answer seems to be better suited now that you added the multiple-choice. You should accept his answer! ;)

Answer (score 4):

$$I=\int \frac{x^9}{(x^2+4)^6}dx=\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{2x(x^2)^4}{(x^2+4)^6}dx=$$
$$x^2+4=u,x^2=u-4,2xdx=du$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{(u-4)^4}{u^6}du$$

Comment: The problem got changed. See my edited answer.

Comment: After the edit, this answer becomes OP's first substitute :)

Answer (score 1):

The substitution $t=1+ 4/x^2$ seems to be useful in your case.

We have $$x^2+4 = \frac{4t}{t-1},$$
$$x^9 \frac{dx}{dt} = - \frac18 x^{12} = -\frac18\frac{4^6}{(1-t)^6},$$
and thus
$$\int  \frac{x^9}{(x^2+4)^6} dx = - \frac18 \int t^{-6} dt. $$

Comment: ^simply because, if you see all the options, you see one thing common. That is $1+4/x^2$. So this is obvious substitution(alteast you have lot of motivation to perform this substitution). Had it be a subjective problem, thinking this substitution would be much harder